# Google Maps API PHP Client - create feature

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api, google-api-php-client

I can't create a feature using Google Maps API PHP Client.
I don't know where to set the coordinates.

My code:

```
$tableID = "xxxx";
$postBody = new Google_Service_MapsEngine_FeaturesBatchInsertRequest();

$feature = new Google_Service_MapsEngine_Feature();
$feature->setType("Feature");

$geometry = new Google_Service_MapsEngine_GeoJsonGeometry();
$geometry->setType("Point");
$point = new Google_Service_MapsEngine_GeoJsonPoint();
$coordinates = "[86.9253,27.9881]"; 
$point->setCoordinates($coordinates);

$feature->setGeometry($geometry);

$properties =  array("gx_id" => "804940557", "mountain_name" => "Mt Everest", "height" => "8848");
$feature->setProperties($properties);

$postBody->setFeatures(array($feature));


$postBody->setFeatures(array($feature));

$service->tables_features->batchInsert($tableID, $postBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm NOT sure about this. There is everything about CURL and JSON in official documentation. But by my quick analysis through github, I guess it's this:
`$feature->setGeometry(array("geometry" => array("type" => "Polygon","coordinates"=>"[86.9253,27.9881]")));`

OR

`$feature->setGeometry(array("type" => "Polygon","coordinates"=>"[86.9253,27.9881]"));`

Comment: didn't work... Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Google_Service_MapsEngine_Feature::setGeometry() must be an instance of Google_Service_MapsEngine_GeoJsonGeometry
But, thanks for the reply.

Comment: IMO the library is full of bugs especially related to type-hinting. There is no method setCoordinates for GeoJsonGeometry but the geometry is required to be a GeoJsonGeometry(and not a GeoJsonPoint, which does have the method). By definition GeoJsonPoint is a GeoJsonGeometry, but the type-hinting makes it impossible to use a GeoJsonPoint as geometry. My suggestion: remove the type-hinting.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. We've already filed an issue on github for this.